# How to add parameters to an object using variables

Tags: python

I am trying to put some variables into a container (object) using a loop.

I created the following class

```
class Box():
    pass
```

now i want to initialize the class and add variables from my textfile to it. My textfile looks like:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
```

I tried following code

```
vars = Box()

filename = ('inputfile.txt')

with open (filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        var_name = str(parts[0])
        var_value = parts[2]
        vars.var_name = var_value
```

I can't find out why this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using a dictionary?

Comment: So what exactly are you hoping to achieve? Even if the code above somehow worked, setting `vars.var_name = var_value` at every iteration means that the value of `vars.var_name` would be  repeatedly overridden, and would eventually attain the value given in the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your help, there were a lot of good and helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is use a class as a storage medium for data. As asongtoruin already said, you could use a dictionary.
Otherwise you need to make the class actually something:

```
class Box():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        return setattr(self, name, value)
```

Then you can use almost all of your code as it was:

```
vars = Box()

filename = ('inputfile.txt')

with open (filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        var_name = str(parts[0])
        var_value = parts[2]
        vars[var_name] = var_value

print(vars.a)
```

Why what you had didn't work was already explained by barak manos: `vars.var_name` does not use the value of the variable `var_name`, because the syntax calling a class method does not support this notation (for good reason).

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
vars.var_name = var_value
```

it's equal to adding the key `'var_name'` to the dict `vars.__dict__`.

I think what you want can be achieved using [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).
instead of `vars.var_name = var_value`, use:

```
setattr(vars, var_name, var_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```
vars[var_name + ''] = var_value
```

(No python code)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use setattr() ?

```
setattr(Box, "var_name", var_value)
```